# In WPF how do I make a page use the style of the container at design time?

Tags: wpf

I am styling a Page in WPF and I want to be able to see the look and feel of that page based on the style of the NavigationWindow that it is in. How do I tell it to use that look and feel from the NavigationWindow at design time?

Comment: Which program's "design time"?